# Keeping only certain columns.. Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object not found

Tags: r, dataframe, knitr, sweave

When I run the following code block I get the error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x' not found. It's referring to the very last line. I'm kinda new to this part of R and don't know what's wrong. After reading the documentation on data.frame the syntax seems correct, but I'm not so sure now.

I'm using a Windows 8 machine and running the code in RStudio using Sweave and knitr.

```
<<read.file,message=FALSE>>=
library(RCurl)
library(xtable)
#READ DATA
con <- getURL("URLforCSVdownloadHere")
x <- read.csv(textConnection(con),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
@

<<clean.file,message=FALSE>>=
#REPLACE SYMBOLS
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\$", "\\\\$", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\%", "\\\\%", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\&", "\\\\&", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\#", "\\\\#", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\^", "\\\\^", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x <- as.data.frame(sapply(x,function(x) {gsub("\\_", "\\\\_", x)}),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#RENAME COLUMNS
colnames(x)[2] <- "Student.Id"
@

<<project.list,include=FALSE>>=
spx <- x[,c(1,9,3,2,10)]

#split
spx <- split(spx,spx$Section)

#row.num func
rnum <- function(x){as.numeric(rownames(x))}

#table func
printProjectList <- function(project.list,i){
  project.list <- project.list[[i]]
  row.names(project.list)<-NULL
  color.rows <- seq(1, nrow(project.list), by=2) 
  print(xtable(project.list, align=c("c","p{2.0cm}","p{1in}","c","p{1in}","p{2in}")), booktabs=TRUE, 
   add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(color.rows), command = rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.9}",length(color.rows))))
}
@
```

Comment: `sapply(x, function(x) ...)` could be trouble.  Try using a different variable list `sapply(x, function(a) gsub(..., a))`

Comment: when I create some dummy data and then knit your document, I get no error message. Maybe the problem has to do with your data. Could you make your data available (for instance by providing "URLforCSVdownloadHere")?

Comment: @Stibu the url is https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=1tG95NRsmQOkevuAs789i-hgwnjbBV4oYT4jc1hSt4Qg&exportFormat=csv

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm not sure what you mean by a different variable list, there's only one data set and I'm trying to clean all of the data with those commands.

Comment: I manage to get your error message now. The reason is (at least in my case) that your first chunk, where `x` is defined, is not a chunk at all, because it misses `<<something>>=` at the beginning. In the second chunk, `x` is then undefined. Also, you should add an `@` after your last line of code. And the last point: I had to change the URL to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tG95NRsmQOkevuAs789i-hgwnjbBV4oYT4jc1hSt4Qg/export?exportFormat=csv.

Comment: @Stibu I've edited my code to include your remarks, I don't see where `x` becomes undefined. I think R should be pulling `x` from the previous lines and it's still designed as the csv file?

Comment: I meant that `x <- sapply(x, function(x) { gsub("\\_", "\\\\_", x)})` is not a good way to pick your variable names.  You're passing `x` into the function that takes the argument named `x`, and then along to `gsub`'s `x` argument.  but `gsub` doesn't know that and it gets lost.  So I think you should change your outside variable names.  Something  like `df <- sapply(x,function(a) {gsub("\\_", "\\\\_", a)})` or you need to explicitly name the `x` argument in `gsub` with `x = x`

Comment: What I meant is that since the code that defines `x` was not inside a Code chunk, it was never executed and thus `x` was never defined. As it is now, your code works for me until I get an error message in the line using `split`, which is due to the fact that you have not included the field `Section` (column 5 in `x`) into `spx`. (Do you try to run your code before you post it?) So, from my point of view, your original problem should be solved, since the error comes from a piece of code you added later. [This file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1551392/sweave_sapply.Rnw) runs for me.

Comment: @Stibu Thanks! Yup, I tried everything I could think of before posting on StackOverflow. The file that you've linked to isn't running for me. When I Compile PDF, I'm getting the same error as I did with my original file: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'x' not found` for Line 27 of your file. Could it be the version of RStudio that I'm using.. I'm using Version 0.98.1090 and R version 3.0.2.

Comment: I have just updated RStudio (thanks for the hint...) and use the same version as you, but I have R version 3.1.2. Have you tried simply running the code chunks (Ctrl-Alt-R in RStudio) instead of compiling the pdf? I must admit that I am quite lost...

Comment: @Stibu Thanks! I updated to R Version 3.1.2. Just tried running the code chunk and I received the error:
`Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In remind_sweave(if (in.file) input, sweave_lines) :
  It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 4; you may need Sweave2knitr("~/.active-rstudio-document") to convert it to knitr
2: running command 'kpsewhich framed.sty' had status 1 ` 
Just wanted to post the error message; I'm trying to figure out what's wrong now..

Comment: @Stibu In line 10, changing the `con <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tG95NRsmQOkevuAs789i-hgwnjbBV4oYT4jc1hSt4Qg/export?exportFormat=csv")` to 
`con <- getURL(
  "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tG95NRsmQOkevuAs789i-hgwnjbBV4oYT4jc1hSt4Qg/export?exportFormat=csv" , 
  .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
)` fixes the problem. Thank you so much!! I'm not exactly sure why this fixes the problem but the Run All works now! :)